# Select of calculated value always returns row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

I have a database (running on postgres 9.3) of bookings of resources. This database contains a table *reservations* which contains beside other values the start and stop time of the reservation (as `timestamp with time zone`)

Now I need to know how much reservations a given company has currently active in the future in terms of total hours of all these reservations added together.

I have put together the following query that does the job:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM Sum(stop-start))/3600 AS total 
    FROM (reservations JOIN partners ON partner = email) 
    WHERE stop > now() AND company = 'givencompany'
```

This works quite well **if** the given company has reservations in the future. The problem I am experiencing is that when the company doesnt have any reservations the query does in fact return a row but the collumn `total` is empty whereas I would like it to return no row at all (or a row containing `0` if nothing is too complicated) in that case.

Is this possible to accomplish with a different `SELECT` or another modification to the database or does the consuming application have to check for `null` every time?

Sorry if my question is trivial but I am very new to databases altogether

---

**Edit**

I found out that I could default the returned value with `0` by using `COALESCE` but I would much prefer it if no row would be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: just add `HAVING Sum(stop-start) IS NOT NULL` at the end of query.

**Long answer**:
This query has no explicit `GROUP BY`, but since it aggregates the rows with `sum()`, it's implicitly turned into a `GROUP BY` query, with all the rows matching the `WHERE` condition taken as one group.

See the [doc on SELECT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#GROUP-BY) :

> without GROUP BY, an aggregate produces a single value computed across
>   all the selected rows

And about the HAVING clause:

> The presence of HAVING turns a query into a grouped query even if
>   there is no GROUP BY clause. This is the same as what happens when the
>   query contains aggregate functions but no GROUP BY clause. All the
>   selected rows are considered to form a single group, and the SELECT
>   list and HAVING clause can only reference table columns from within
>   aggregate functions. **Such a query will emit a single row if the HAVING
>   condition is true, zero rows if it is not true.**

Comment: I would like to give you an extra +1 for not only solving my issue but also explaning why it works.

Comment: Thanks. A word of appreciation is more worthy than points anyway :)